# Connecting object instance to user in django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to use `models.ForeignKey('User')` to connect my model to the auth user in django.  But when I try to submit my form to create a new object instance the form won't validate and I get the error `... has no column named user_id`.  Is there some other way I am suppose to be connecting my objects to the auth.User or is more information needed to answer this question?

EDIT:

sqlall gives:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "checker_check" (
   "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   "title" varchar(80) NOT NULL,
   "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
   "video" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   "text" text NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE INDEX "checker_check_fbfc09f1" ON "checker_check" ("user_id");
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What's the point of posting your SQL table? What about the actual model class? Also, *please* don't truncate your error message - the traceback is there for a reason. Post it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Foreign Key field after the table was created? If so you'll have to add that manually. If you don't care about losing the data in your db then this should work:

```
python manage.py reset app_name
```

If you do need to keep the data the following sql statement should work:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN user_id integer
```

Comment: hmmm, did think of that. I'm using South so I didn't think it would be an issue but I guess with auth it's still an issue.

Comment: @DanLearningphp actually haven't used South yet. Let me know if that works or if the problem is elsewhere, be interested to learn more about how South works.

Comment: problem seems to be elsewhere.  I've tried recreating the database and it didn't seem to effect the problem.

Comment: hmm.. what does your db table structure look like when you run python manage.py sqlall app_name from the command line? Does everything look right?